# VB.net Reading a text file twice (Best practice - to close then re-open? Alternative?)

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I am writing an assembler for a self taught course I am doing.

I have a text file I read in to a dictionary structure.

I then need to reread the same text file, but obviously I am already at the end of that file.

How do I reset to the beginning again?  What is the best practice?

Thank you.

Comment: How big are the files you're dealing with?

Comment: How are you reading the file? Using a Stream reader? I think `File.ReadAllLines` or `File.ReadAllText` would be better.

Comment: How would I use this method to assign each line to a new entry in an array if it meets a certain condition?

Comment: The answer is good, but why must you read the file twice? If you load it into memory once it should be more efficient to read if from memory the second time.

Comment: Noted; would it be best to load text into a list then use the list to populate a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize the [`BaseStream` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.basestream?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader_BaseStream) to get access to the underlying stream (when reading a local file, this will be a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.8)), then reset the stream's [`Position` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.position?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Stream_Position) to rewind it to the beginning.

```
Dim Reader As New StreamReader("somefile.txt")
Dim Contents As String = Reader.ReadToEnd()

Reader.BaseStream.Position = 0

Dim FirstLine As String = Reader.ReadLine()
```

Comment: @BinaryFinary Glad I could help! Good luck with your project.

Comment: @BinaryFinary The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: My apologies - I'm new.  thank you for informing me!  Consider it done!